# Video not responsive in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, responsiveness

I am placing video players with playlists iframed on a WP page. I have them wrapped with a div that has responsive css applied both to the div and the iframe with padding-bottom etc. Problem is when viewed on a mobile device the video is not resizing to fit the width of device. I emailed myself direct links to the videos and they loaded/resized correctly, so i know its not the videos.

Here are two pages each having a different version of a video player, one of them is a Youtube player:
http://events.latimes.com/screenings/gallery-test-2/

http://events.latimes.com/screenings/html5-videos-test/

Any help would be immensely appreciated as i've been on this for too long and need to resolve it. Let me know if I can post extra info or any code snippets to be help in troubleshooting.

Comment: an update: it seems resizing on the iPad is good, its only on the iPhone that the video comes out real big. If this could be replicated on a browser I could use chrome dev tools to troubleshoot, it loads just fine on chrome and in dev tools.

Comment: sorry scratch that update: no good on iPad either. plz help, running out of time on this

Comment: Posting the solution to help others. iframe needs to be placed in another div with any class/id, then apply the following css:
.video-container {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 83.25%;
 padding-top: 35px;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe {
 display:block;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

[see on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jon_U/00zyaybp/)

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 53.2%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
 
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


/* avexdesigns.com say use 56.25% above if your video has a 16:9 aspect ratio */
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GA1Nr0SNEYE?rel=0" width="853" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>


<!--- Many Thanks to
http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/
for this solution
-->
```